# Creating a Site Column from an External List with SharePoint 2010?

Tags: bcs, site-column

Can you create a Lookup column from an External List within SharePoint 2010.  I have achieved this before but it seems incredibly fragile and I am now wondering if this is even a supported feature and is there any documentation to provide guidance?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to use an External Data Column, there is no need for you to go via the External List to your External Systems data.

[External Data Column on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee559346.aspx)